# Tensorflow model.fit() printing duplicate messages with no error

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have been trying to use TensorFlow in python to train some Neural Networks (NN) on my local machine. I get this weird bug that the model.fit method is printing loss and other metrics multiple times during the training of a single epoch. There is no error during the training, and the training works perfectly fine. It's just the duplicate messages output making it hard for me to track progress.

I have tried to re-install tensorflow, it did not solve the problem. I have also trained multiple different NN, some are simple MLP, some are CNN. And the problem persists for all my NNs. Any advice would be really appreciated.

Here is a screenshot of the weird messages output:
[Weird message output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MysB9.png)

I would like output like this:
[desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WOEIz.png)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is really strange. In model.fit you did not specify the verbose parameter. The documentation [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model) does not define the default mode but apparently it is verbose=1 since you are getting a progress bar. Try setting verbose=2 and see if things print out correctly. I am assuming you inputs are arrays is that correct?
If arrays what is the dimensions of the arrays? You did not specify a batch_size so it defaults to 32. The printout shows that it is taking 586 steps per epoch so that implies you have about 586 X 32=18752 samples is that correct?

Comment: Thanks, Gerry. My inputs are an array of arrays. And the inner arrays are just the images for the CNN. Verbose = 2 definitely makes the output readable. I am getting 1 line of loss and accuracy per epoch now.
Epoch 1/5
586/586 - 57s - loss: 0.0370 - accuracy: 0.9875

Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: Yeah, I have about 19000 training images, sized at (224, 224). I am using Resnet50 as base model. Batch size are the default 32. Labels are binary.